# When button is clicked, spawn a new button with its own counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which create new button on each click with counter.

However I want counter for the individual buttons. How should modify my code so each of the button has their own counter.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function clickME() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode(clicks);

  btn.onclick = clickME;

  btn.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clear, do you want the whole component to be created with counter (including the `<p>`), or do you want button text to be incremented on individual button click?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can mock up screen shot showing what you want to achieve.

Comment: It looks as if you received some potentially good answers to your question. You may want to consider accepting the one which best meets your needs. Accepting answers is _always completely optional_ - but it is recommended, as it is one way to help future visitors find useful answers more easily. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking to make the button text counts with each click, just use the innerHTML attribute of the button and add it to itself:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function clickME() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode('0');

  

  btn.appendChild(t);
  
  btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.textContent = (+btn.innerHTML) + 1;
  };
  
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

In case you want to add the whole component with `<p>` as the counter, notice that I remove the component and added a button once clicked it will generate a new container div along with counter `<button>` and `<p>` tag that holds the counter value:

```js
function clickME() {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  var btnText = document.createTextNode('Click me');
  btn.appendChild(btnText);
  
  var pTag = document.createElement("p");

  pTag.innerHTML = 'Clicks: ';
  var aTag = document.createElement("a");

  aTag.textContent = '0';
  pTag.appendChild(aTag);
  
  btn.onclick = function() {
    aTag.innerHTML = (+aTag.innerHTML) + 1;
  };
  
  container.appendChild(btn);
  container.appendChild(pTag);
  
  document.body.appendChild(container);
}
```

```html
<button id="add-counter" onclick="clickME()">add counter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your function into a class and handle each instance separately. By default this will offer you separate objects to handle separate counters.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id of count container in the listener and get count from and there increment it. Don't append the button in body instead append in the parent node of count container.

```js
function clickME(click) {
  var clicks=parseInt(document.getElementById(click).innerHTML);
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById(click).innerHTML = clicks;

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode(clicks);

  btn.onclick = clickME;

  btn.appendChild(t);
 document.getElementById(click).parentNode.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="clickME('clicks')">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

<button type="button" onClick="clickME('clicks1')">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks1">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function clickME() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button").length;
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode(buttons + 1);

  btn.setAttribute("id", buttons + 1);
  btn.setAttribute("class", "button");
  btn.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  var p = "Clicks for button " + (buttons + 1) + ": <a id='clicks_" + (buttons + 1) + "'>0</a>";
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p);
}

function clickButton(element) {
  let id = element.id;
  let buttonClicks = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-count");
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.getAttribute("class") == 'button') {
    let id = e.target.id;
    let buttonClicks = document.getElementById("clicks_" + id).textContent;
    buttonClicks = parseInt(buttonClicks) + 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks_" + id).textContent = buttonClicks;
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button").length;
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode(buttons + 1);

    btn.setAttribute("id", buttons + 1);
    btn.setAttribute("class", "button");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    
    var p = "Clicks for button " + (buttons + 1) + ": <a id='clicks_" + (buttons + 1) + "'>0</a>";
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btnClicked(e) {
    var innerText = e.currentTarget.innerText;
    var currentCount = innerText.match(/\d+/)[0];
    currentCount++;
    e.currentTarget.innerText =`Clicked ${currentCount} times`;
    var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var text = document.createTextNode('Clicked 0 times');
    btn.appendChild(text);
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnClicked(event)');
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <button class="btn" onclick="btnClicked(event)">Clicked 0 times</button>
    </div>
```